# Conjugation action on relative homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $K$ be a subgroup. Suppose $g \in G$ commutes with every element of $K$. Is it true that conjugation by $g$ will act trivially on $H_*(G,K)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $H_*(G,K)?$

Comment: By $H_*(G,K)$, I mean the homology of the mapping cone $BK \to BG$.

Comment: I don't think this is true. If I did not miscalculate then the integral Heisenberg group, and its central subgroup, gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

According to the paper *"Comparison of relative group (co)homologies"* there are distinct versions (which agree for certain pairs of groups). But I expect the answer to be yes in any sensible version, by mimicking the proof in Brown's bible (Corollary III.8.2).

For example, if K is a normal subgroup of G, then Corollary 4.29 of that "comparison" paper says $H_\ast(G,K)\cong H_\ast(G/K)$. The action should respect this isomorphism, hence trivial.